# HTML Showing 5 items in dropdown

Tags: html, css, height, html-select

I am trying to show 5 items in dropdownlist and add a scroll bar after that records. I tried adding height etc to select and could not succeed. Even size property is not what I am looking for. Do we have any property to set height of dropdown list and add scroll after showing certain number of records?

[dropdown list](http://jsfiddle.net/UVCX9/)

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
     <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [html select scroll bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901089/html-select-scroll-bar)

Comment: You'll need jquery for this. I've used the select2 plugin for this before. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that's operating system/browser behavior that cannot be changed.

Here are some similar questions with the same responses... and I'm not aware of any recent HTML/CSS tricks to do it either.

- [HTML Select + limit number of options visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530173/html-select-limit-number-of-options-visible)
- [How do I set the max number of items visible in a SELECT drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752046/how-do-i-set-the-max-number-of-items-visible-in-a-select-drop-down)
- [How can I limit the visible options in an HTML  dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788245/how-can-i-limit-the-visible-options-in-an-html-select-dropdown)

Answer (score 3):

```
<select onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=5;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
     <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
```

[Test Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cSSjF/270/)